# How do I iterate over a nested dictionary and a nested list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

**Python Question:** How to iterate through a nested dictionary and a list and output one student record at a time.

Most of the responses I have researched show iteration through a Python nested dictionary (no list included) and output is usually the full dictionary i.e. all items (keys/values) not one at a time. Note: Cannot use functions for this yet.

The explanations and code are below...

I assumed 5 Students. Each student has; name, ID and 5 grades

At the start of the program, a user is asked for input i.e.,'how many grades should be entered for each student?'

when the user inputs the figure, data about individual students, and only number of grades inputted is provided. Ideally one at a time.

The program  should continue to let the user input additional new students until the user tells the program to stop inputting new ones.

The output for part 1 should be...

```
How many grades should be entered for each student?:

Entering data for student_1:
Student's name: Ford Michael
Student's ID number: 567651
Enter grade #1: 92
Enter grade #2: 93
Enter grade #3: 82
should we add another student? (y/n):
```

'''

```
# Part 1, a dictionary of students was created, then a 'for' loop as below..

students = {

    'student_1': {
    'first': 'Ford', 
    'last': 'Michael',
    'id_number': '567651', 
    'grade_1': 92,
    'grade_2': 93,
    'grade_3': 82,
    'grade_4': 85,
    'grade_5': 85
    },

    'student_2': {
    'first': 'Toyota',
    'last': 'Corolla', 
    'id_number': '567651', 
    'grade_1': 82,
    'grade_2': 83,
    'grade_3': 92,
    'grade_4': 95,
    'grade_5': 85
    },

    'student_3': {
    'first': 'Geely', 
    'last': 'Maye', 
    'id_number': '231341', 
    'grade_1': 99,
    'grade_2': 83,
    'grade_3': 82,
    'grade_4': 95,
    'grade_5': 85
    },

    'student_4': {
    'first': 'Beema', 
    'last': 'Eel',
    'id_number': '453551', 
    'grade_1': 79,
    'grade_2': 83,
    'grade_3': 88,
    'grade_4': 85,
    'grade_5': 85
    },

    'student_5': {
    'first': 'Tucson', 
    'last': 'Hyundai',
    'id_number': '564351', 
    'grade_1': 98,
    'grade_2': 97,
    'grade_3': 90,
    'grade_4': 92,
    'grade_5': 85
    },
}

# To determine number of grades to pull from dictionary for each student (input)
    grade_entry = input("\nHow many grades will be entered for each student? : " )

# To convert str into a numerical value, integer, 'int'
    grade_entry = int(grade_entry)


# While 'for' loop works it is  not pulling data one after the other

if grade_entry == 5:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']
        grade_1 = student_info['grade_1']
        grade_2 = student_info['grade_2']
        grade_3 = student_info['grade_3']
        grade_4 = student_info['grade_4']
        grade_5 = student_info['grade_5']

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Students's ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Enter grade #1: {grade_1}")
        print(f"Enter grade #2: {grade_2}")
        print(f"Enter grade #3: {grade_3}")
        print(f"Enter grade #4: {grade_4}")
        print(f"Enter grade #5: {grade_5}")

elif grade_entry == 4:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']
        grade_1 = student_info['grade_1']
        grade_2 = student_info['grade_2']
        grade_3 = student_info['grade_3']
        grade_4 = student_info['grade_4']
        

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Students's ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Enter grade #1: {grade_1}")
        print(f"Enter grade #2: {grade_2}")
        print(f"Enter grade #3: {grade_3}")
        print(f"Enter grade #4: {grade_4}")
        
elif grade_entry == 3:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']
        grade_1 = student_info['grade_1']
        grade_2 = student_info['grade_2']
        grade_3 = student_info['grade_3']

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Students's ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Enter grade #1: {grade_1}")
        print(f"Enter grade #2: {grade_2}")
        print(f"Enter grade #3: {grade_3}")

elif grade_entry == 2:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']
        grade_1 = student_info['grade_1']
        grade_2 = student_info['grade_2']

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Students's ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Enter grade #1: {grade_1}")
        print(f"Enter grade #2: {grade_2}")
                
elif grade_entry == 1:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']
        grade_1 = student_info['grade_1']

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Student's ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Enter grade #1: {grade_1}")
    
else:
    for student_data, student_info in students.items():
        print(f"\nEntering data for: {student_data}")
        full_name = f"{student_info['first']} {student_info['last']}"
        id_number = student_info['id_number']

        print(f"Student's name: {full_name.title()}")
        print(f"Student`enter code here`'s ID number: {id_number}")
        print(f"Note: Number of grades for each student was not entered! ")
 
# Attempts to use option 2 below resulted in errors


# Created a list of grades for each student
student_1_grades =  [ 92, 82, 85, 85, 92 ] 
student_2_grades =  [ 82, 83, 92, 95, 88 ] 
student_3_grades =  [ 99, 83, 82, 95, 85 ] 
student_4_grades =  [ 79, 83, 88, 85, 85 ] 
student_5_grades =  [ 98, 97, 90, 92, 85 ] 

# Created a student dictionary for each student with grades
student_1 = {
    'Name': 'Ford Michael', 
    'ID': 567651, 
    'Grades' : [ 92, 82, 85, 85, 92 ],
    }

student_2 = {
    'Name': 'Toyota Corolla',
    'ID': 567651, 
    'Grades' : [ 82, 83, 92, 95, 88 ],
    }

student_3 = {
    'Name': 'Geely Maye',  
    'ID': 231341, 
    'Grades' : [ 99, 83, 82, 95, 85 ],
    }

student_4 = {
    'Name': 'Beema Eel', 
    'ID': 453551, 
    'Grades' : [ 79, 83, 88, 85, 85 ],
    }

student_5 = {
    'Name': 'Tucson Hyundai', 
    'ID': 564351, 
    'Grades' : [ 98, 97, 90, 92, 85 ],
    }

#Question: How to iterate through a nested dictionary and a list and output one item at a #time.
```

## EDIT:

'''
The output should be this....

## allow user input info on number of grades to pull

How many grades will be entered for each student? : 1

## code prints for first student in the dictionary and asks if should continue

Entering data for student # 1:
Student's name: Amanda Turner
Student's ID number: 835643
Enter grade #1: 95
Should we add another student? (y/n): y

## If 'y', it pulls second user in the dictionary, if 'n' ends and prints results

Entering data for student # 1:
Student's name: Allan Field
Student's ID number: 735643
Enter grade #1: 92
Should we add another student? (y/n): n

- Input completed -

Here is a review of the student data..

Student # 1:
Name: Amanda Turner
ID: 835643
Grade: 95

Student # 1:
Name: Allan Field
ID: 735643
Grade: 92

-End of program -

Comment: you have the same code in all `for`-loops co you could put it in function and run the same function many times.

Comment: you should run code in some loop - like `while True`

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to do. You say you want to `output`, next you say you want to `input` but finally you have all data aready in code.

Comment: don't waste time for separated variables `student_1`, `student_2` but put all directy in one dictionary `students`

Comment: you have nested data so you should use nested `for`-loop. Inside `for student_data, student_info in students.items():` you could use `for number in range(grade_entry)` and add items directly to main directory without `grade_1`, `grade_2` - and then you will no need all `if grade_entry == 5:` `if grade_entry == 4:`

Comment: if you want to add grades then you should use `input()` to ask for values but you get values and add them to directory - but you get data from existing directory.

Comment: @furas, Thank you so much. Specifically says not to use a function yet.  A while True loop, with everything in a nested dictionary and list in a for-loop will work. But don't know how to do this i.e. allow user input how many grades to pull, then iterate over the dictionaries and lists to access the grades and pull the number of grades and the  students data (name, ID and grades), and then store and print these.

Comment: I am new to programming and to stack overflow...is there a place to put/send a screen shot?

Comment: if you have new information then edit question and append at the end (with some header - like `EDIT:`) - but don't put screenshots with text because we can't copy text from image to use it in solutions.

Comment: @furas I have updated the expected outcome at the end of the question see  'Edit:'. This is in response to request for clarification on what the program ultimately should do. How would you do it without defining a function and using the while true, and for-loops suggested?